A problem with on_voice_state_update, python, disnake

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print("Участник присоединился к голосовому каналу")
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="Участник присоединился к голосовому каналу", color=0x00ff00)
        embed.add_field(name="Участник", value=member.mention)
        embed.add_field(name="ID участника", value=member.id)
        embed.add_field(name="Канал", value=after.channel.mention)
        embed.add_field(name="ID канала", value=after.channel.id)
        await disnake.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, id=1240402311147290685).send(embed=embed)
        join_time_dt = datetime.strptime(join_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=moscow_tz)
        join_time = member.voice.joined_at.astimezone(moscow_tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
            leave_time = datetime.now(tz=moscow_tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            leave_time_dt = datetime.strptime(leave_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=moscow_tz)
            duration = leave_time_dt - join_time_dt
            hours_on = duration.seconds // 3600
            minutes_on = (duration.seconds // 60) % 60
            seconds_on = duration.seconds % 60
            embed = disnake.Embed(title="Участник отключился от голосового канала", color=0xFF0000)
            embed.add_field(name="Участник", value=member.mention)
            embed.add_field(name="Канал", value=before.channel.mention)
            embed.add_field(name="ID канала", value=before.channel.id)
            embed.add_field(name="Время в канале", value=f'{hours_on} часов, {minutes_on} минут, {seconds_on} секунд')
            await disnake.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, id=1240402311147290685).send(embed=embed)

Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\filat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\filat\Desktop\vc\bot\main1.py", line 249, in on_voice_state_update
    duration = leave_time_dt - join_time_dt
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'join_time_dt' where it is not associated with a value

New fixes
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong =(The variable doesn't see most likely because of if\elif as I understand it
How to make a variable initialized

member.voice is None, you have to check for it, not for before.channel.members.

Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\filat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\filat\Desktop\vc\bot\main1.py", line 246, in on_voice_state_update
join_time = member.voice.joined_at.astimezone(moscow_tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'joined_at'

Added a check as you said, 0 effect

Not only do you have to add a check, you also have to skip that line if the result of the check is that member.voice is None.

But if I skip a line, it won't output the time I need.

Do you have any ideas how to do it differently? Since I've already tried what you're suggesting

If I understand correctly you want to output the time when a member joined, in the event that the member leaves. But when the member leaves, you cannot access it anymore. You have to save the time the member joins when it joins, not when it leaves.

Is it worth using a database? Or the simple variable above?

You should only need a variable for this.

But I could not output from the variable above to the lower one

Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\filat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\filat\Desktop\vc\bot\main1.py", line 249, in on_voice_state_update
duration = leave_time_dt - join_time_dt
^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'join_time_dt' where it is not associated with a value

Here's what it gives out when trying to do it your way

Then you did it wrong. I don't know what you did.

Added the changes above, please take a look

join_time and join_time_dt have already been swapped if anything

raceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\filat\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\filat\Desktop\vc\bot\main1.py", line 245, in on_voice_state_update
join_time = member.voice.joined_at.astimezone(moscow_tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'joined_at'

There is also such an error
